# Serving Compressed files through Google storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gzip, brotli

I want to serve the static files for my website from **Google storage buckets**. For that I want to compress the files, Thought of using **Brotli** compression but some browsers are not supporting **Brotli compression**. So they are suggesting to use **gzip** as a fallback.

I don't know If there is anyway to serve the files from **google storage** based on the browser support. for example if the browser supports **brotli** it should fetch the **brotli** version or it should fetch **gzip**.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your deployed application should be able to determine in more than one way which browser is used by client. You may find related information on the web, for instance [Detecting device and browser](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/concepts/Detecting_device_and_browser/). Once browser detected, your app may decide to use Brotli or gzip compression, to suit the detected browser's capabilities.